# TextView text alignment not working within collectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uitextview, text-alignment, text-align

I’m having trouble with my TexView here And this method  `textview.textAlignment = .natural`won’t work I couldn’t figure out what the problem is here the text only stick to the left side no matter what the language is, now this textview is inside a collectionViewCell, I have tried to work around with the NSSting attributes didn’t work tried also to set the text alignment outside of the Cell didn’t work here is my code you will find `messageTextView.textAlignment` everywhere and all of this places I set it into didn’t work

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "orderReview", for: indexPath) as! OrderReviewCell
        
        let order = orderreview[indexPath.item]
        
        cell.textBubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        cell.messageTextView.textAlignment = .natural
        cell.messageTextView.textColor = .black
        cell.messageTextView.text = order.order
        cell.textBubbleViewRightAnchore?.isActive = false
        cell.textBubbleViewLeftAnchore?.isActive = true
        
        if let imgUrl = order.profileImg, imgUrl != "" {
        cell.profileImg.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlStringAndPlaceHolder(urlString: imgUrl)
        }
        cell.profileImg.isHidden = false
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 2, right: 0)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        var height: CGFloat = 80
        let order = orderreview[indexPath.item]
        if let text = order.order, text != "" {
            height = estmatedFrameForText(text: text).height + 20
        }
            
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    
    private func estmatedFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
        let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesDeviceMetrics)
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.natural
        return NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),  NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style ]).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, context: nil)
    }

}


class OrderReviewCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    
    let messageTextView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        tv.textAlignment = .natural
        tv.backgroundColor = .clear
        tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()
    
    let textBubbleView: UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    let profileImg: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView(image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "ProfileHolder"))
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        img.layer.masksToBounds = true
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return img
    }()
    
    var textBubbleViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var textBubbleViewRightAnchore: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var textBubbleViewLeftAnchore: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    
        addSubview(textBubbleView)
        addSubview(messageTextView)
        addSubview(profileImg)
        
        setupLayout()
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    func setupLayout(){
        
        profileImg.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        profileImg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        profileImg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        
        textBubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textBubbleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        textBubbleViewWidth = textBubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        textBubbleViewWidth?.isActive = true
        
        textBubbleViewRightAnchore = textBubbleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8)
        textBubbleViewRightAnchore?.isActive = true
        
        textBubbleViewLeftAnchore = textBubbleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImg.rightAnchor, constant: 8)
        textBubbleViewLeftAnchore?.isActive = true
        
        messageTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        messageTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.textBubbleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        messageTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        messageTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.textBubbleView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the goal ? Is it when the language is for example arabic, you want the text to start from the right instead of from the left in your textview ?

Comment: Yeah that’s it,